# How to fix Horizontal scrolling script which I wrote in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've made up this Horizontal scrolling page based on some idea from YouTube, everything works fine, the logic is also fine, but the translation of x has a problem, sometimes it translates X too much or sometime lower than what it should, there must be a change made on translateThisMuch const, but I cannot think of anything, any help would be greatly appreciated.
this is the link to the code https://codepen.io/AbramPlus/pen/RwwoPrW
Notice how when it goes from different parts of the scrolling sections to others, there is still some of the other ones left in the view port.
this is the JS code.

```
const spacer = document.querySelector(".spacer");
const spacerSecond = document.querySelector(".spacerSecond");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const windowEffect = document.querySelector(".windowEffect");

const horizontalScrollEnabler = () => {
 const scrollFromTop = window.scrollY;
const translateThisMuch = scrollFromTop - spacer.offsetTop;
const spacerHeight = window.innerWidth * 4 ;
const spacerSecondHeight = spacerSecond.offsetHeight;



    if (scrollFromTop > spacer.offsetTop && scrollFromTop < spacerSecond.offsetTop && scrollFromTop + window.innerHeight < spacerSecond.offsetTop + spacerSecond.offsetHeight) {
        windowEffect.style.position = "fixed";
        wrapper.style.transform = `translateX(-${translateThisMuch}px)`;
        windowEffect.style.top = "0";
    }

    if (scrollFromTop < spacer.offsetTop) {
        windowEffect.style.position = "absolute";
        windowEffect.style.top = "0";
    }

    if (scrollFromTop > spacer.offsetTop + spacerHeight) {
        windowEffect.style.position = "absolute";
        windowEffect.style.top = `${window.innerWidth * 4}px`;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(horizontalScrollEnabler);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", horizontalScrollEnabler);
```

Comment: Why no one helps? No one gives a hint, why StackOveFlow is like this? Only old answers are helpful, I'll almost never get any help here. It's been 2 days and 0 help or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is when you scroll after the starting point of Horizontal scroll section, upward, since the scrolling can easily bypass the starting point which implements the whole code and translation of X,it may jump 20px, or 10px, or 5 px, the wrapper keeps the Xtrasnlation which it had before scrolling up causing the whole element being left out from being trasnlated by the script, since scrolling up or scrolling down isn't being done 1 pixel at every scroll event. So How do we fix it? 
We can extend our starting or ending point by just few hundred pixels so even if we bypass the previous starting or ending points caused by our scrolling down from ending point or scrolling up from our starting point we can still have access to scrolltop - the starter element's offsetTop and define if it is lower than 0 so lets the translation of X of wrapper element to be 0 or if it is bigger than where the end point is it should be equal to -translation of X equal to ending point.